# How to make a single component have the same image like the link path (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, api

The first is I already make my character list to have an image loop for each name, in my assets I have images 1,2,3, and until 10.jpg.

I make it like this for the list :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActorService } from 'src/app/core/services/actor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actor-list',
  template: `
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="columns is-multiline" *ngIf="actors">
          <div class="column is-4" *ngFor="let actor of actors; let i = index">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-content">
                <a [routerLink]="'' + (i+1)" >{{ actor.name }}</a>
                <figure class="image is-4by3 mt-6">
                  <img src="./assets/img/{{ i + 1 }}.jpg"  alt="">
                </figure>
                <p><br>Height : {{ actor.height }}</p>
                <p>Birth Year : {{ actor.birth_year }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ActorListComponent implements OnInit {
  actors;

  constructor(private actorService: ActorService) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.actors = await this.actorService.getActors()
    console.log(this.actors)
  }

}
```

But on the single one that if we click the first actor ex. Luke Skywalker I wanted to be image one only appear and so on.
And this is for the actor-single component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ActorService } from 'src/app/core/services/actor.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actor-single',
  template: `
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card" *ngIf="actor">
          <section class="hero is-info">
            <div class="hero-body">
              <h1 class="title is-1 ml-4 mb-6">{{ actor.name }}</h1>
            </div>
          </section>

            
          <div class="message-body" *ngFor=" let i = index">
              <figure class="image is-4by3 mt-6">
                <img src="./assets/img/'{{ i + 1 }}.jpg"  alt="">
              </figure>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Height : {{ actor.height }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Mass : {{ actor.mass }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Hair Color : {{ actor.hair_color }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Skin Color : {{ actor.skin_color }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Eye Color : {{ actor.eye_color }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Birth Year : {{ actor.birth_year }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Gender : {{ actor.gender }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Created : {{ actor.created }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Edited : {{ actor.edited }}</h2>
            <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Url : {{ actor.url }}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class ActorSingleComponent implements OnInit {
actor;
  constructor( private actorService: ActorService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params.subscribe(async params => {
      const actorname = params['actorname'];
      this.actor = await this.actorService.getActor(actorname)
      console.log(this.actor)
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the what you wanted, but an Idea :

Shall you name your file to the name of the actor ?

If yes, you could use it like that

```html
<div class="message-body">
  <figure class="image is-4by3 mt-6">
    <img [src]="'./assets/img/' + actor.name + '.jpg'" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Height : {{ actor.height }}</h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Mass : {{ actor.mass }}</h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">
    Hair Color : {{ actor.hair_color }}
  </h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">
    Skin Color : {{ actor.skin_color }}
  </h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">
    Eye Color : {{ actor.eye_color }}
  </h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">
    Birth Year : {{ actor.birth_year }}
  </h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Gender : {{ actor.gender }}</h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Created : {{ actor.created }}</h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Edited : {{ actor.edited }}</h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle is-4 ml-6 mb-1 pd-0">Url : {{ actor.url }}</h2>
</div>
```

*Another tip : remark how I did use, `[src]="..."` in Angular world, this is consider a bad practice to use `{{ }}` within an html attribute.`*

Voilà

Comment: Thank you that one can do, but what I wanted is the second code one to be fix, single person one

Comment: @JansenSu There you are, with an additional tip ;)